# I am looking for the most efficient way to toggle navigation

Tags: jquery, html, navigation

I am looking for the most efficient way to toggle navigation sub-menus, below is the HTML, i can get each sub menu to toggle display however i only want one sub menu to display at all times:

```
<nav id="main-nav">
<ul>
<li id="home">&nbsp;</li>
<li id="about">ABOUT<ul id="about-sub"><li><a href="/overview/">Overview</a></li><li><a href="/news/">News</a></li><li><a href="/the-board/">The Board</a></li><li><a href="/partners/">Partners</a></li><li><a href="/contact/">Contact</a></li></ul></li>
<li id="iiag">IBRAHIM INDEX (IIAG)<ul id="iiag-sub"><li><a href="/iiag/">Overview</a></li><li>Country Profiles</li><li><a href="interactive-index/">Interactive Index</a></li><li><a href="/advisory-council/">Advisory Council</a></li><li><a href="/iiag-methodology/">Methodology</a></li></ul></li>
<li id="prize">IBRAHIM PRIZE<ul id="prize-sub"><li><a href="/ibrahim-prize/">Overview</a></li><li><a href="/laureates/">Laureates</a></li><li><a href="/prize-committee/">Prize Committee</a></li></ul></li>
<li id="forum">IBRAHIM FORUM<ul id="forum-sub"><li><a href="/ibrahim-forum/">Overview</a></li></ul></li>
<li id="FS">FELLOWSHIPS &amp; SCHOLARSHIPS<ul id="FS-sub"><li><a href="/fellowships/">Fellowships</a></li><li><a href="/scholarships/">Scholarships</a></li></ul></li>
<li id="media">MEDIA</li>
<li id="DL">&nbsp;</li>
</ul>
```

I am using jquery to achieve the toggle:

```
$('#about').click(function()  {
            if ($('#about-sub').css('display')=='none')
            {$('#about-sub').css('display', 'block');} 
            else {$('#about-sub').css('display', 'none');}
```

});

I have tried adding in an extra if to the statement however the code will just get rather long for each nav section.

Surely there is one function for what i am trying to achieve?

Any help...

Comment: Most people use too many classes, but you use too many IDs. Just give your sub-menus the class `sub-menu` and target them via their parent, e.g. `#about > .sub-menu`

Comment: That's not "too many classes", that's polymorphism :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your CSS:

```css
#about-sub { display: none }
.about-show { display: block }
```

Then use http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/ to toggle `.about-show` on and off.

Answer (score 0):

First, cache references to the elements you have queried :

```
var $aboutSub = $('#about-sub');
```

And then use `$aboutSub` instead of `$('#about-sub')`

There is no point browsing the DOM and comparing tons of IDs on every click.

Second :

```
var $allLis = $('#main-nav li');

$allLis.on('click', function() {
    $allLis.hide(); // All the li elements
    $(this).show(); // Currently clicked li element
});
```

Should probably work. Adapt it to your case if needed.
Note that if you dinamycally add or remove elements from your nav, you will have to modify the code above.

**EDIT** : Well i didn't see you had sub-lis. So i assume this solution is wrong. That's what happens when you have a crappy code identation.

Comment: Well the solution your provided was wrong but it was adaptable. I got what i wanted at the end.